# Too many re-renders. When setting state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to make an e-commerce app using expo with typescript and I'm having issues with loading my categories page.
There's two ways which one can access the category page

1. Through bottom nav - this one works fine
2. Through buttons on the home page

Trying to setState based off the params that's coming in through the homepage but it's giving me the Too many re-renders error.
Below is the code that I currently have for it.

The default needs to be there because of the first method of entering the category page, I've tried putting a conditional as the default category, but category wont change the second time if being accessed through the home page again.

```
export default function CategoryList(props: Props) {
  let { params } = useRoute<StackRouteProp<'Home'>>()

  const [currentCategory, setCategory] = useState({categories: Categories[0]});

  if (params) {
    setCategory({categories: params.categories})
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise with what the expected behavior should be. The answers below all seem to think you want to only `setCategory` once when the component mounts, but then your responses imply otherwise. It isn't clear what you want the code to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `useEffect` with `useRef`:

```
export default function CategoryList(props: Props) {
  let { params } = useRoute<StackRouteProp<'Home'>>()

  const [currentCategory, setCategory] = useState({categories: Categories[0]});
  const canSet = useRef(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (params && canSet.current) {
      setCategory({ categories: params.categories })
      canSet.current = false
    } else {
      canSet.current = true
    }
  }, [params])
```

Comment: Thanks @nicodp, similar issue to the comment I put above, the `isSet` will always be set to `true` afterwards, so the next time the page is hit with a different selected category, it wont change

Comment: I edited my answer with `canSet` ref, check it out.

Comment: Yes it did!!! Thanks for your help. Didn't need useRef though, got rid of it completely and worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you call `setCategory`, it will re-render the component. Then, every time you render the component, if `params` exists, it will call `setCategory` again, which will cause another render, which calls `setCategory` again, and so on and on until it hits React's render limit.

One possible way to work around this would be to add a boolean to set after the first time which will prevent it from going inside the `if` block the second time:

```
const [currentCategory, setCategory] = useState({categories: Categories[0]});
const [hasParamsCategory, setParamsCategory] = useState(false);

if (params && !hasParamsCategory) {
  setCategory({categories: params.categories});
  setParamsCategory(true);
}
```

This still isn't perfect because in general it's not a good practice to directly call state-changing functions during render, but this will serve as a quick and dirty workaround.

Comment: Thanks Peter, however, `setCategory` still wouldn't run anymore than the first time because `hasParamsCategory` will always be set to true

Comment: Is `params` changing again after the first time?

Comment: Yes it is, it changes based on the category that's selected from the home page.

Comment: Are you calling `setCategory` anywhere else? If not, you can just make `currentCategory` a `let` instead of a `const` and do `currentCategory = params.categories`

Comment: unfortunately setCategory is called multiple times, any other suggestions? Or is there a better method of setting a state from param?